# Unix TCP port scanner

Tags: c, unix, tcp, port-scanning

I have a TCP port scanner that scans all the open ports on a given IP and returns only the open ones and the name of the service that runes on it. To do this I create a socket, set it to non-blocking mode, and `select()` on a port if it timeouts it means the port is closed, else is open. The problem is my select() always timeouts even when I try to scan open ports. I would like someone to point me to my mistake, is my logic bad?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;
fd_set    working_set;
hostent *he;
char* protoc [2] = { "tcp","udpn" };
int port;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
int sendfd;
servent *srvport;
void set_nonblock(int socket) {
    int flags;
    flags = fcntl(socket,F_GETFL,0);
    assert(flags != -1);
    fcntl(socket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
}
void set_block(int socket) {
    int flags;
    flags = fcntl(socket,F_GETFL,0);
    assert(flags != -1);
    fcntl(socket, F_SETFL, flags | ~O_NONBLOCK);
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

    struct timeval  timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec  = 1;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    char* host = argv[1];
    char* pro = argv[2];
    int portlow  = atoi(argv[3]);
    int porthigh = atoi(argv[4]);

    fprintf(stderr, "n Scanning host=%s, protocol=%s, ports: %d -> %d   \n",
            host, pro, portlow, porthigh);

    if(strcmp(pro, protoc[0])==0)
        pro = protoc[0];
    else if (strcmp(pro, protoc[1])==0)
        pro = protoc[1];
    else
    {
        herror("n specify valid protocol - tcp or udpn");
        exit(-1);
    }


    if((he = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL)
    {
        herror("n *** gethostbyname() failed ***n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    /*In case TCP protocol is selected for scan, app opens streaming socket

for every port to be scanned, tries to connect to it, and if successful

it displays information about service using struct servent.
*/

    if(strcmp(pro, protoc[0])==0) // tcp scan
    {
        for(port = portlow; port <= porthigh; port++)
        {
            // open stream socket
            if((sendfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
            {
                perror("*** socket(,SOCK_STREAM,) failed ***n");
                exit(-1);
            }
            set_nonblock(sendfd);
            bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

            servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
            servaddr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);
            int res = connect(sendfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
int ser;
            if (res < 0) {
                 if (errno == EINPROGRESS) {
                    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
                    timeout.tv_usec = 10;
                    FD_SET(sendfd, &working_set);

                    if ((ser=select(sendfd+1, NULL, &working_set, NULL, &timeout)) > 0) {
                          srvport = getservbyport(htons(port), protoc[0]);

                    }
                    else {
                       fprintf(stderr, "Timeout or error() %d\n",ser);
                       perror("select(): ");

                    }
                 }
                 else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                 }
                 if(srvport != NULL)
                     printf("tport %d: %sn   \n ", port, srvport->s_name);
                 else if (ser=0)
                   close(sendfd);
                 fflush(stdout);
              }

            //set_block(sendfd);
        }//end of for()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That's quite a lot of code. I didn't run it. However, this:

```
if (ser=(select(sendfd, NULL, &working_set, NULL, &timeout)) > 0) {
```

is wrong. The first argument to `select()` is "the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1" (see [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)).

Also, you should parenthesize like so:

```
if ((ser = select(...)) > 0) {
```

since now you're assigning the result of the `>` operator to the `ser` variable, which is probably not what you expect.

Comment: I fixed this errors , but now i get a list of all ports , is the way i am closing the socket also bad ? Also i updated the code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the I/O descriptor set, working_set, you need to make sure that you clear it:

```
FD_ZERO(&working_set);
```